# Error serializing export interface, Unable to load transformation [null] : can't find directory

Tags: repository, pentaho

I used a Transformation Executor to call another transformation, Under browse I defined the variable as ${trans_path} however when I run it on the server it complains about the following error "Unable to load transformation [null] : can't find directory "

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the trans executor have a write to log step output the value of that variable. It’ll allow you to check whether the variable is being passed correctly.

The log output should appear on you catalina.out file under tomcat’s lot folder.